# Robocopy Error 53 when not logged in. When logged in, Robocopy runs successfully

Tags: batch, scheduled-tasks, robocopy

We run a nightly scheduled task that copies files from a local drive to a network share.

When I'm remoted in to this machine using any account, Robocopy runs fine. When I'm not logged in, Robocopy gives ERROR 53 'The network path was not found'.

The scheduled task runs:

- As a service account that does have access to the network share
- 'Run whether user is logged on or not' is selected
- 'Do not store password' is not selected
- 'Run with highest privileges' is checked
- 'Configure for Windows 10' is selected, given it's running on a Windows 10 machine

The script is fairly simple:

```
robocopy D:\ "\\folder\ " /E /COPY:DAT /W:10 /R:10 /A-:SH /xd "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information" /LOG:"D:\Logs\File.log"
```

I do have a space after "\folder\ " to ensure the files copied to a network share.

Thank you for your help